# Haskell : Float to IO Float

Tags: haskell, io

I have a type problem with this function

```
type Store = [(String, Float)]
evalParser :: String -> Store -> Float -- Boring function who returns a Float

programme :: Store -> IO()
programme store = do
    putStr "@EvmInteractif:$> "
    instruction <- getLine
    putStrLn (show instruction)

    if (estCommande (instruction) == True) then
        do
            res <- evalParser instruction store
            putStrLn "TODO: execution de la commande"
            programme store
```

And at the line of res's affectation I have this error :

Couldn't match expected type `IO Float' with actual type`Float'
    In the return type of a call of `evalParser'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: v <- evalParser expr store

Can someone tell me the rigth syntax please ? 
Thanks

Comment: Use `let res = ...` instead of `res <- ...`

Comment: `estCommande (instruction) == True` ~ `estCommande (instruction)`

Comment: Slightly tongue-in-cheek solution: since `res` isn't used anywhere, you can just delete the offending line. But only slightly tongue-in-cheek, as there's a lesson here, namely: I suspect you believe that merely calling `evalParser` will "do something", but it won't. This smells like you have made a bit of a mistake; e.g. perhaps `evalParser` should be returning an updated store to use in the later recursive call to `programme`, or perhaps you intended to print the result, or both. Or perhaps you did those in the original but cut them out to make a minimal example, in which case kudos!

Answer (score 2):

`evalParser` is pure, you don't need to use do notation to call it. To shimmy fix it, you could just wrap it in a `return` to stick it in the IO Monad:

```
res <- return $ evalParser instruction store
```

To avoid the wrapping/unwrapping altogether though, just don't treat it as an impure value from the start:

```
let res = evalParser instruction store
```

Comment: Since "arrows" are a notion with their own syntax perhaps we should stick to calling it "do notation" or "monadic bind" to avoid causing confusion later on.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I originally had "do notation", but it didn't sound right to me. I haven't written Haskell in a couple years, so I've forgotten some terminology. I'll change it back. Thanks.